# mgo.v2 not unmarshaling nested map in struct and instead set bson.M

Tags: mongodb, go, mgo

Currently am working in a Go project and using mongo with `gopkg.in/mgo.v2` am having issues retrieving values from the database, I have a structure like:

```
type person struct {
    Name string
    Age  int
    MyMap map[string]interface{}
}
```

Later, I have a function that am calling to get the results (its part of an interface):

```
func(m SomeInterface) Get(filter bson.M, target interface{}){
     collection := m.Db.C("myCollection")
     err := profilesCollection.Find(filter).One(val)
     if err != nil {
        panic("error reading from mongo")
    }
}
```

and I call this function as:

```
p := person{}
myinterface.Get(somefilter, &p)
```

After doing this, p.MyMap is of type `bson.M` and not `map[string]interface{}`...why? and how could I get instead the map and not bson.M? Thanks

Comment: 1) they're the same type; [`bson.M` is `map[string]interface{}`](https://godoc.org/gopkg.in/mgo.v2/bson#M); 2) you should move off of mgo.v2 as it's been deprecated and is no longer being maintained.

Comment: The driver uses `bson.M` to unmarshal if you pass an `interface{}`. If you need `map[string]interface{}`, you have to convert `bson.M` into `map[string]interface{}` by recursively processing and copying data.

Comment: @Adrian yeah, I read that, it's a very big project and I dont own it so, difficult to migrate. So, should I use something like json marshal/unmarshal to assign it correctly to my struct?

Comment: @BurakSerdar no you don't. The types are equal, you can just type convert `m := map[string]interface{}(myBsonM)`.

Comment: That easy: https://play.golang.org/p/bCqhJAIQ_4_S

Comment: @Adrian, for nested objects, `m["key"]` will give you back a `bson.M` even though `m` is `map[string]interface{}`.

Comment: There's no indication in the post that there are nested objects; and if there are, the nested `bson.M` are still just underlying `map[string]interface{}`. So they can be used as-is, or type converted the same way if it's really necessary (which it likely isn't).

Comment: @Adrian, they cannot be used as-is if the code using them type asserts them to `map[string]interface{}`, which is something most recursive json-processing code do.